# No up button after setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) and NavDrawer

Tags: android

In my project I'm forced to extend some base activity which in it's turn extend ABS and creates navigation menu.
When my activity called, in onCreate I called

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`

but there is no up button appear near the app icon. Instead NavDrawer icon remain there (the three horizontal stripes near the app icon).
How can I change the navdrawer icon to ordinary back button ?

Comment: show us some more code it should work. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: On what kind of device are you testing? On Android 2.x you won't see it.